# set 2 values in a ternary operation - C

Tags: c, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm having trouble setting two ints using ternary operators in C. I can't seem to find an answer as most questions relate to multiple ternary conditions.

Whereas, I want to check for one condition and set 2 values accordingly.

Ie:

```
if ( i == 5 ) {
    x = foo;
    y = foo + 1;
} else {
    x = bar;
    y = bar + 1;
}
```

so far I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
x, y = ( i == 5 ) ? foo, foo + 1 : bar, bar + 1;
```

is it possible to set two values in ternary after checking 1 condition?

thanks,

Comment: Why not stick with the if statement - readable, maintainable etc. A ternary operator is just syntactic sugar. Keep code simple to understand. Easier to debug. Easier to fix. ....

Comment: @Olaf - Would this be a good idea in Python?

Comment: No, there is no support for tuples in C. If your example was real code, the correct answer would be to use the ternary operator to set `x`, and then `y=x+1`.

Comment: in python it's common practice to return several parameters. so I would say yes.

Comment: @EdHeal: Not this one (and not that same syntax, of course). But yes, you can use the ternary operator that way. As much as you can nail a piano to your knee :-)

Comment: thanks everyone, "tuples" that was the key I was missing, but I get it now for C. I usually use if / then statements but every once in a while, I like to exercise my brain with some ternary. And I figured I would try it on this occasion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  Unlike python or perl which supports assigning to a list of numbers, C does not support this syntax.

You'll need two separate ternary operations to do this:

```
x = (i == 5) ? foo : bar;
y = (i == 5) ? foo + 1 : bar + 1;
```

In the case that you only want the conditional to run once (e.g. it's a function call or some other expensive operation):

```
int result = (i == 5);
x = result ? foo : bar;
y = result ? foo + 1 : bar + 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want to use something a bit ugly, this would work:

```
x = (i == 5) ? (y = foo + 1, foo) : (y = bar + 1, bar);
```

By using the comma operator, the left side of the operator is evaluated (in this case, an assignment to `y`) and discarded while the right side becomes the value of the expression which subsequently gets assigned to `x`.

Note that the parenthesis are not strictly needed for the "if" portion, but they are needed for the "else" portion.

This is an abuse of the language however.  Better to stick with something more readable.

Comment: Interesting use of the comma operator... mine are simpler but still not recommended.

Comment: @chqrlie What you have works in OP's particular case where the values of `x` and `y` are related.  The above will work in general.

Comment: I did at first take advantage of the relation, but your approach inspired a more general alternative: `(i == 5) ? (x = foo, y = foo + 1) : (x = bar, y = bar + 1);` just as ugly, but easy to extend to any number of assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function:

```
void setAndIncrement(int val, int *x, int *y) {
    *x = val;
    *y = val + 1;
}

....

(i == 5) ? setAndIncrement(foo, &x, &y): setAndIncrement(bar, &x, &y);
```

But this will not make anything better or easier to maintain. You should really just stick with the `if` and `else`. It is easy to read, maintainable and all round exactly the way you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

As @dbush says, you can't do that in C.  In C++ you can use various tuple types, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

So why not?  In Python and many newer languages, the comma operator bundles values (loosely speaking) together so they can be treated as a unit.  That's what Python does, and what permits `x,y = 1,2 if a else 3,4` to work.

In C, however, the comma operator separates *expressions* or *statements*, not *values*.  `a,b` evaluates `a`, throws away the result, evaluates `b`, and provides the result of evaluating `b` as the result of the comma.  At no point are `a` and `b` considered together.

(C wizards and language lawyers: for the sake of readability by the OP, I am deliberately eliding lvalue/rvalue considerations and other finer semantic points.  Yes, you are correct that a full answer should not do so. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Although I would not recommend using a single ternary operation for this, it can be done. If it is just a challenge, here are some solutions:

```
y = 1 + (i == 5 ? (x = foo) : (x = bar));
```

alternately:

```
y = 1 + (x = i == 5 ? foo : bar);
```

Or more general:

```
(i == 5) ? (x = foo, y = foo + 1) : (x = bar, y = bar + 1);
```

As you can see, all of these are somewhat contorted and not very readable.

If you can write 2 statements, I would recommend:

```
x = (i == 5) ? foo : bar;
y = x + 1;
```

Comment: thanks, yeah in the end 2 statements offer a little bit more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Various ways to meet the goal of setting two values:

Of course the first is clean and easy to read.

```
if ( i == 5 ) {
    x = foo;
    y = foo + 1;
} else {
    x = bar;
    y = bar + 1;
}
```

Another is to set `N` fields of one object and assign that using C11 *compound literals*.  This works with `?:` as code is setting one object.

```
  int i = rand(), foo = rand(), bar = rand();
  typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
  } xyz_T;
  xyz_T xyz = (i == 5) ? 
      (xyz_T ) { .x = foo, .y = foo + 1, .z = 1 } : 
      (xyz_T ) { .x = bar, .y = bar + 1, .z = 2 };
```